# Win10 Bluetooth slider missing

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, drivers, bluetooth

Using Windows 10 pro 64bit, the slider to turn Bluetooth on and off does not appear in the settings window. The bluetooth adapter does indeed show up in DevMgr, albeit with a Caution sign attached. So the computer is recognizing that it has an adapter, but that's about where it stops. I have tried;

- Device Manager - uninstalling driver, restarting. Disabling the Bluetooth device and re-enabling. DevMgr says driver is the most up-to-date.
- Unregistering btmshellex.dll (regsvr32 /u btmshellex.dll)
- Installing brand new drivers from Asus website (laptop mfg)
- Uninstalling anything that says Bluetooth under Installed Apps/Programs

I do get some errors that i haven't been able to link together in my searches.

1) While attempting to unregister/re-register btmshellex.dll, i get the error "The module 'btmshellex.dll' failed to load.

2) Under the device's properties in Device Manager, i get the error "This device cannot start. (Code 10) STATUS_DEVICE_POWER_FAILURE"

3) Under Services, BluetoothUserService and BluetoothUserService_55f38 are both stopped. When i try to start them, i get "The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled or because it has no enabled devices associated with it."

Comment: The slider missing is a symptom. The issue is the device and/or the driver. Is this an internal device built-in to the system, or an external device you added on later? Have you pursued warranty service on it if it's built-in?

Comment: Built-in, and it is far out of warranty service. I have not recently opened the case either, so there is no chance it became unplugged

Comment: Then the most likely problem is that the hardware is faulty. You could try purchasing an inexpensive external BT dongle and see if it works.

Comment: That's unfortunate, but you may be right. I recently performed a new install of Win10 as my previous install's bootmanager got corrupted, and the bluetooth was working beforehand. I only did an OS install, not a full format and install